# Split the column into several and unpivot the columns

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-3

I currently have 2 columns `NOM_CONCAT` and Number of concat(COUNT_RSF_)

which is composed of" concat "from 0 to 5

```
A1, B1, C1 ...

A2

A3, B3

.
.
```

My goal and to separate the column `NOM_CONCAT` in several columns under PyQGIS
except that this does not mean this to separate.

Without hiding, the end goal is to rotate the generated columns.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
uri="C:\impression_plan\mini\RSFFicheCanalisation.shp"

v1= QgsVectorLayer(uri, "RPG_grille_2018", "ogr")
all_features = v1.getFeatures()
v1.startEditing()
pr = v1.dataProvider()
#l=1
idx = v1.fields().lookupField('COUNT_RSF_')
idmax =  v1.maximumValue(idx)

print(idmax)
v1 = iface.activeLayer()
fieldindex = v1.fields().indexFromName("NOM_CONCAT") 

v1.startEditing() 
for feat in v1.getFeatures(): 

    if feat[fieldindex]: 
        fields = feat[fieldindex].split(', ')
        print(fields)

        for i in range(1, len(fields)): 

            feat[fieldindex + i] = fields[i - 1] 
            v1.updateFeature(feat) 
    else: 
        continue 
v1.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(v1)
v1.updateFields
```

[image]

Comment: Give us an example of input columns and output columns in your attribute table. Use Excel or a spreadsheet if that helps.

Comment: thank you for your answers I added a photo to the question

Comment: So you only want the FIRST item from NOM_CONCAT?

Comment: @wingnut looks like the goal is to have a separate row for each item in NOM_CONCAT

Comment: I see. The OP'S code is modifying existing features rather than creating new ones. @patrickblancseau - you need to create new features for every A,B,C class in a NEW layer. Don't modify the existing layer features. It will be neater.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use "[Split features by character](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-features-by-character)" tool.

```py
uri = r"C:\impression_plan\mini\RSFFicheCanalisation.shp"

layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "", "ogr")

new_layer = processing.runAndLoadResults(
                "native:splitfeaturesbycharacter",
                {'INPUT': layer, 
                 'FIELD':'NOM_CONCAT',
                 'CHAR':', ',
                 'REGEX': False,
                 'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})["OUTPUT"]
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]